# Xamarin.Forms ImageCell binding to a local file

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using data binding in a ListView to bind a list of ImageCells. The image is a file stored locally on the device as app data.

On Windows, using an absolute or relative path to the file does not work, I have to convert it to a file:// URI. Unfortunately, on Android, the file:// URI doesn't work, and it needs to be a path.

I'm currently working around the issue by using a different value in the view model depending on the target platform. Is there a better solution than this:

```
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows) {
    result.uri = new Uri(uri).AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding Uri}"
               Text="{Binding Name}">
    </ImageCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The type of `Uri` is string, do I need to use a `UriImageSource` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating converter and dependency service.

**Xaml**

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5,20,5,0" >
  <ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}" ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath, Converter={StaticResource AndroidImageInvert}}">
        </ImageCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

**Converter**

```
public class ByteImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        string fileName = value as string;
        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(DependencyService.Get<IWRDependencyService>().GetImageBytes(fileName)));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Dependency Service**

```
    public byte[] GetImageBytes(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = fileName.Replace(".jpg", "").Replace(".png", "");

        var resId = Forms.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier(
          fileName.ToLower(), "drawable", Forms.Context.PackageName);


        var icon = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Forms.Context.Resources, resId);

        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        icon.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, ms);
        byte[] bitmapData = ms.ToArray();
        return bitmapData;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, this is really complex. Isn't it easier to just convert to a file:// URI in the view model, depending on whether the platform is Windows?  I.e., https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files/blob/master/src/client/MobileAppsFilesSample/ViewModels/TodoItemImageViewModel.cs#L31.

Comment: I couldn't find simple solution like Windows so settled with the above solution. If you come across easier way please post it.

Comment: I updated my question with my current solution, it's just 2 lines of code.